# Jest / Enzyme - Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component I am trying to test. It looks like so -

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { CATEGORY_TYPES } from '../../constants';

import './ResultCard.sass';

const ResultCard = ({ result, onSelectResult = null }) => {
  const { guid, category, postcode, condition } = result;
  const { value, image } = CATEGORY_TYPES.find(asset => asset.type === result.category);

  return (
    <article className="media result-card is-marginless" onClick={() => onSelectResult()}>
   <!-- omitted for brevity -->
    </article>
  );
};

export default ResultCard;
```

This is tested as such using the follow test case -

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import { ResultCard } from '../../../src/components';
import { CATEGORY_TYPES } from '../../../src/constants';

describe('.ResultCard', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const { wrapper } = setup({});

    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});

const setup = propOverrides => {
  const props = Object.assign(
    { result: { guid: '61934c1f-ce55-5cc7-e1d7-18b391fe7944', postcode: 'ab12 3cd', category: 'foo', condition: 'bar' } },
    propOverrides
  );
  const wrapper = shallow(<ResultCard {...props} />);
  return { wrapper };
};
```

However I am getting the following error from my test runner -

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

       7 |   const { guid, category, postcode, condition } = result;
       8 |   const { value, image } = CATEGORY_TYPES.find(asset => asset.type === result.category);
    >  9 |
      10 |   return (
      11 |     <article className="media result-card is-marginless" onClick={() => onSelectResult()}>
      12 |       <figure className="media-left">
```

I am unsure how I can introduce the component logic around CATEGORY_TYPES into my component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly mistake, I was passing in 'foo' and expecting to find it on my CATEGORY_TYPES array, which wouldn't work as it doesn't exist